# FormControl element undefined once ngIf is placed on form element

Tags: angular

i have a child component dynamically created inside a parent that handles the `<form>` group. The child looks like the following:

```js
<div>
    <input [name]="name" #password="ngModel" required [(ngModel)]="pendingAccount.Password" />
    <input *ngIf="withPasswordRepeat" name="repeatedPassword" #repeatedPassword="ngModel" required  [(ngModel)]="pendingAccount.RepeatedPassword" />
</div>
<div *ngIf="!password.valid || (repeatedPassword !== undefined && !repeatedPassword.valid)">this is invalid...</div>
```

Even though both input fields are shown `repeatedPassword` keeps undefined whereas `password` is fine and hence the validation does not work as expected. But when looking at the NgForm Object that is being maintained by the parent component, the `repeatedPassword` FormControl is part of the NgForm object.

When i remove the `*ngIf` directive everything works as expected when it comes to showing the `this is invalid...` text.

So from the typescript perspective everything works but once `*ngIf` is applied, it seems like `repeatedPassword` keeps `undefined` and accessing repeatedPassword in the template (e.g. {{repeatedPassword}}) is not possible.

Can anybody explain to me why this is the case and is there is any solution without getting rid of the `*ngIf` directive?

Thanks in advance, best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work because `#repeatedPassword` is not known in the template when using `*ngIf`. If you write it out "desugared", it looks like this:

```html
<div>
    <input [name]="name" #password="ngModel" required [(ngModel)]="pendingAccount.Password" />
    <ng-template [ngIf]="withPasswordRepeat">
      <input name="repeatedPassword" #repeatedPassword="ngModel" required  [(ngModel)]="pendingAccount.RepeatedPassword" />
    </ng-template>
</div>
<div *ngIf="!password.valid || (repeatedPassword !== undefined && !repeatedPassword.valid)">this is invalid...</div>
```

As you can see, your reference variable is only available inside the `ng-template`, so you can't use it outside of that environment. To avoid this problem, have a look at reactive forms. A "cheap" solution would be to not remove the element using `*ngIf` but rather just hide it visually using CSS.

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure whats the actual problem but i guess with a slight modification in the code we can achieve what you are looking for.

```
<div>
<input *ngIf="!withPasswordRepeat" [name]="name" placeholder="test" #password="ngModel" 
required [(ngModel)]="pendingAccount.Password" />
<input name="repeatedPassword" placeholder="test2" #repeatedPassword="ngModel" required  
[(ngModel)]="pendingAccount.RepeatedPassword" />
</div>
```

check out the working stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngif-fqwp2b

consider accepting the answer if alright :)

Comment: This is not a solution to the problem i mentioned.

Comment: Please explain what do u want to achieve, if possible i'll help.